# WCF to consume other REST Services?

Tags: wcf

I'm trying to figure out if the best way to consume and use a 3rd party API that is REST is to use `WCF` or just use `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json` Namespace or the `WebClient` object in .NET and create my own methods to send and receive json objects to and from the REST service I'm consuming.

So far I've only seen consuming REST json of an existing WCF service.  Can you use WCF to consume and work with (request/response) any json based REST service outside of .NET?

Comment: That should be possible as any REST Service is defined just using Http protocol and from your point i see WCF as a (client) that needs the feature to invoke/consume a REST service defined.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can consume Flickr services using WCF as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2008/04/21/how-to-consume-rest-services-with-wcf.aspx).  You just need to change the ResponseFormat in the WebGet (and WebInvoke) attributes to be Json.

However, my experience is that it is rather painful when you deal with stuff like error handling or complex authentication schemes.  I found it simpler to manually write the client using the [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) class.